# mule 4 : http request from one api to another - correlation id being sent implicitly but not other headers

Tags: mule, mulesoft, mule4

Am using Mule runtime 4.4
Have two api - api 1 receives request over http and then calls api2 again over http
api 1 receives a GET request with two headers:

```
X-Correlation-Id = abcd
X-Channel = Music
```

api 1 then makes a call to api 2 BUT it does NOT send any of the headers

However when request is received in api2 we can see the header `X-Correlation-Id = abcd` ( unexpected behaviour ? )

However the other header `X-Channel = Music` is missing ( expected behaviour )

Here is the complete code :
`api1 :`

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<mule xmlns:http="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http" xmlns="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core"
    xmlns:doc="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/documentation"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core/current/mule.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http/current/mule-http.xsd">
    <http:listener-config name="HTTP_Listener_config" doc:name="HTTP Listener config" doc:id="f1bec56d-de65-4a93-913d-07a7426d6bf6" >
        <http:listener-connection host="0.0.0.0" port="9091" />
    </http:listener-config>
    <http:request-config name="HTTP_Request_configuration" doc:name="HTTP Request configuration" doc:id="7040eda0-aff5-47c2-8682-be73489e2c2c" >
        <http:request-connection host="localhost" port="9092" />
    </http:request-config>
    <flow name="header_pass_01Flow" doc:id="dc0c28a7-c277-4192-b641-e73af8afbde3" >
        <http:listener doc:name="Listener" doc:id="57e56cd6-a47e-456b-8c6d-e57627c673b8" path="/pass/*" config-ref="HTTP_Listener_config"/>
        <logger level="INFO" doc:name="Logger" doc:id="6df37e5e-a491-421c-a642-742059107d95" message="before call to api 1"/>
        <http:request method="GET" doc:name="Request" doc:id="a6765e5d-40f5-4abd-bff6-d6e6a80eecdf" config-ref="HTTP_Request_configuration" path="/receive/all"/>
        <logger level="INFO" doc:name="Logger" doc:id="e250696f-7109-42a4-a50c-586fc164fed9" message="after call to api 1"/>
    </flow>
</mule>
```

`api2 :`

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<mule xmlns:http="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http" xmlns="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core"
    xmlns:doc="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/documentation"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core/current/mule.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http/current/mule-http.xsd">
    <http:listener-config name="HTTP_Listener_config" doc:name="HTTP Listener config" doc:id="a1f75f77-5ff5-4346-866e-0f1ce1679e57">
        <http:listener-connection host="0.0.0.0" port="9092" />
    </http:listener-config>
    <flow name="header_receive_01Flow" doc:id="433cc316-549d-4349-86ba-68e3571a5716" >
        <http:listener doc:name="Listener" doc:id="d3677aa5-bd38-41d4-ba33-cb4a8a1fd2b2" config-ref="HTTP_Listener_config" path="/receive/*"/>
        <logger level="INFO" doc:name="Logger" doc:id="6999dea6-c369-4813-a5e6-8e81ec98ef60" message="received call"/>
    </flow>
</mule>
```

How is it that `X-Correlation-Id`  is implicitly being passed ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [correlation id](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-runtime/4.4/correlation-id) is the identifier for Mule events, meaning is part of the core functionality of Mule 4. Other attributes or headers are added either by connectors or custom code/operations. Some connectors like the HTTP connector send it by default.